# ProxyPass redirect to the same path

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, wildfly, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have two management console wildlfy and I want to access to both of them through reverse proxy. For that I did this conf in my httpd reverse proxy:

```
<VirtualHost X.X.X.X:80>
ServerName reverse.com

ProxyPreserveHost On
RewriteEngine On

<Proxy balancer://wildfly-1>
BalancerMember http://wildfly-1.com route=wildfly-1 disablereuse=On keepalive=On retry=20
ProxySet lbmethod=bybusyness
</Proxy>

RewriteRule ^/wildfly-1-console/?$ / [R]
ProxyPass / balancer://wildfly-1/ stickysession=JSESSIONID nofailover=Off
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://wildfly-1/

<Proxy balancer://wildfly-2>
BalancerMember http://wildfly-2.com route=wildfly-2 disablereuse=On keepalive=On retry=20
ProxySet lbmethod=bybusyness
</proxy>

RewriteRule ^/wildfly-2-console/?$  / [R]
ProxyPass / balancer://wildfly-2/ stickysession=JSESSIONID nofailover=Off
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://wildfly-2/

</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is that when I enter `http://X.X.X.X:80/wildlfy1` or 2 it works, the rewriterules works perfectly and redirect to the management console, But only for the first console. I think that the problem is with my rewriterules, it redirect to the same path "/", so my reverse ignore the second redirection. How can I solve that ?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot have `/` redirected to two different URLs.  Apache will match the first one and ignore the rest of the config.  So you have to distinguish between wildfly1 and wilfly2 in the URL.  Remove both `RewriteRule`s and modify your `ProxyPass /wildfly1-console balancer://wildfly1/ ...`, same thing for `ProxyPassRevers` and the one for wildfly2.  another point, you can do this without using balancers.  Balancing is when you have two instances of the same thing.  Here you are just redirecting directly.

Comment: Thank you @Nic3500 for your answers. I test your solution but when I enter http://reverse.com/wildlfy1-console it is looking locally for the console. and for the balancing if I don't do that it gives me a syntax error "ProxyPass unknown Worker parameter" for the stickysession and i need it.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

this was to long or a comment.  This is what I meant:

```
<VirtualHost X.X.X.X:80>
    ServerName reverse.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RewriteEngine On

    ProxyPass        /wildfly-1-console http://wildfly-1.com
    ProxyPassReverse /wildfly-1-console http://wildfly-1.com

    ProxyPass        /wildfly-2-console http://wildfly-2.com
    ProxyPassReverse /wildfly-2-console http://wildfly-2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This way heach URL is served via a proxy to another site.
Note that this is far from a complete configuration, it is just to show the concept.  I was also no able to test it, as I have no access to an Apache right now.

As for the sticky session, you are applying balancer concepts to a single member, so it serves no purpose.  The sticky cookie is to ensure you will return to the same instance for every request.  Here is you ask for no1, you get no1.  If you ask for no2, you get no2.  It is not possible for you to ask for `/wildfly-1-console` and be "proxied" to http://wildfly-2.com.

Now if you want to have a single URL to proxy in front of http://wildfly-1.com AND http://wildfly-2.com, that is a subject for another question (well some research on your part :-)

Comment: Hi @Nic3500. I tested this before but the problem persist. When I try to access directly to the console wildfly-1 http://wildlfy-1.com/ it redirects me natively to http://wildlfy-1.com/console/App.html and when I try it behind my reverse with the `ProxyPass / http://wildlfy-1.com/` conf it works. but with the ProxyPass set like this `ProxyPass /wildfly-console1 http://wildlfy-1.com/` it doesn't work, and when I enter http://revese.com/wildfly-1-console it redirect me locally with http://revese.com/console/index.html so I don't know where is the problem.